# Android setText skip a line <br> /n \n

Tags: android

hello :) im trying to make my game type:

Current score: X

In : Y seconds
(between them, skip a line.)
 Here is the code I tried to use:

```
changingTextView.setText("current score:"+counter+ \n- +"in"+TimeCounter+"seconds");
```

The \n or /n is not working to me.. 
I also tried :

```
changingTextView.setText("current score:"+counter+ <br> +"in"+TimeCounter+"seconds");
```

It is not working too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
changingTextView.setText("current score:"+counter+ System.getProperty("line.separator") +"in"+TimeCounter+"seconds");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `<br>` as

```
changingTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("current score:"+counter+ "<br>" +"in"+TimeCounter+"seconds"));
```

And make sure your \n is in "\n" for it to work.

```
changingTextView.setText("current score:"+counter+ "\n" + "-" +"in"+TimeCounter+"seconds");
```

Comment: @user3740786 Happy to help,If this answer or any one solved your issue then mark it as accepted and upvoted so it may help others also,having similar issue,anyway enjoy coding.

Comment: You are right, I tried to but I couldn't because you need to wait some time until you can mark as accepted, and also I don't have 15 rep to upvote an answer.

Comment: @user3740786 ok bro,enjoy coding.